# TypeError: $(...).runner is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails-4

```
  I am trying to use the jquery  runner plugin. but i am unable to use is since it is giving error TypeError: $(...).runner is not a function. Can anyone tell me how to use it and where to include it. I have included it in application.html.erb file but it is not working
 ## this is the jquery call
 $('#butt').click(function() {
   $('#runner').runner('start');
 });
```

HTML:

```
   <div id="runner">
     <a href='#' id='butt'>click</a> 
   </div>
```

GEM:

```
     gem 'runner', '~> 0.0.0'
```

Application.html.erb

```
  <%= javascript_include_tag 'application',media: 'all', 'jquery.runner.js' => true %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag 'application',media: 'all','jquery.js' => true %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js" %>
 <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/modernizr/2.6.2/modernizr.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http:////cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

application.js:

```
    //= require jquery
    //= require jquery_ujs
    //= require twitter/bootstrap
    //= require turbolinks
    //= require moment
    //= require_tree .
    //= timer 
    //= require runner.js
    //= runner.js
    //= require runner
```

Comment: it's more helpful to include the generated code for your server includes. The not a function error usually means the plugin is missing or the path is wrong. Basically, the page thinks it is not defined in your code